# Custom Search in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to implement a custom search feature in my Rails app.

I have 3 tables `User` `Company` and `CompanyUser`

My relations declared are as follows

```
class CompanyUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
...
end
```

In Company.rb

```
has_many :company_users, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :company_users
```

In User.rb

```
has_many :company_users, dependent: :destroy
has_many :companies, through: :company_users
```

and in my view page I'm listing all companies using company_users table
Now i have a search field where I can type a name in it which filters this list of company users.

I'm calling a method from my CompanyUsers table to filter the search result like this

```
@company_users = CompanyUser.all
if params[:search_data].present?
  @company_users = @company_users.filter_company_users(params[:search_data])
end
```

where params[:search_data] is passed to the same method when search data is entered in the search field.

this is the method that do the search filtering.

```
 def self.filter_company_users(search_data)
    where('company_id like (?)', "%#{search_data}%")
 end
```

Right now I can get the result only if I type the correct `id` of CompanyUser table in that search field. What I'm trying to do is to search  using fields from User table and Company Table. For eg `email` from User and `name` from Company.

Comment: Nopes.. I tried that before.. It gives error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class CompanyUser
  def self.search(search_data)
    search = self.joins(:company, :user)
    search.where!('company_users.company_id LIKE :query OR users.email LIKE :query OR companies.name LIKE :query', query: "%#{search_data}%")
    search
  end
end
```

With the `join` statement you join the `CompanyUser` table with the company and the user, therefore you will be able to apply filters on that tables too.

The where condition reuses the same query string and applies the search in `OR` to all the columns you want to search for.

Answer (score 1):

```
@company_users = CompanyUser.all
@copany_users.all(:conditions => ["company_id LIKE ? OR company.email like ? OR user.name LIKE ?","%#{params[:search_data]}%","%#{params[:search_data]}%", "%#{params[:search_data]}%" ])
```

**or**

```
def self.filter_company_users(search_data)
where("company_id LIKE ? OR company.email like ? OR user.name LIKE ?" ,"%#{search_data}%", "%#{search_data}%","%#{search_data}%")
end
```

Comment: You can't query other tables unless you join them. Moreover, the first query uses a very old signature of the `all` method which is no longer supported in recent Rails versions.